# What is this BIONICLE limb piece?

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

In [Kooberz's video,](https://youtu.be/BPCCsYUgj2I%3Cbr/%3E) he uses this piece.
What is it called?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Bricklink indicates that this is the [*"Bionicle Toa Nuva Leg Section."*](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=43557#T=C&C=1)

[image]